# How to Use ReportViewer in AutoCAD 2014 Plugin

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, autocad

### Goal

I want to be able to use ReportViewer to generate reports on employee computers.

### Current Situation

I am developping an AutoCAD plugin with Visual Studio 2010. The plugin works correctly and we have been using it (on employee computers as well) for a couple months now. Since I have Visual Studio 2010 installed, I'm guessing that the package for ReportViewer assembly has been installed at the same time.

### Problem

When the employees try to generate a report they get the error:

> Cannot load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

I have tried installing [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) but to no avail.

Any ideas?